# error in emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

When I run my application on emulator, I get the following:

```
[2011-07-30 02:51:52 - HelloTabWidget] Failed to install HelloTabWidget.apk on device 'emulator-5554!
[2011-07-30 02:51:52 - HelloTabWidget] (null)
[2011-07-30 02:51:52 - HelloTabWidget] Launch canceled!
```

The ErrorLog shows the following error:

```
Error
main.xml: Error during post inflation process:
TabHost requires a TabWidget with id "android:id/tabs".
View found with id 'tabs' is 'com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Mock
```

No command output when running:

```
am start -n com.sign.set/com.sign.set.HelloActivity -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
```

on device emulator-5554.

Comment: To me, the error message appears pretty clear about what's wrong...

Answer (score 1):

This means that you have an error in your main.xml file, so the program isn't compiling, and therefore isn't getting loaded onto the device.

It looks like the error is that you didn't assign your TabWidget an id, so it may be fixed if you just add `android:id="@android:id/tabs"` within your TabWidget declaration in main.xml, but it would be easier to tell if you posted your xml file.

Check [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html) for a tutorial on using tab views. Note item number 4, which shows a sort of minimal XML file.